# Binding a dynamic automationID to every ListViewItem in a ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In my current project for my company I am trying to set up automationIDs for every UI element in my WPF application.

Inside a ListView there are several ListViewItems which i want to be accseeible through automationIDs. So I'm trying to set up an automationID for every ListViewItem inside the ListView that looks like 'dataitem1', 'dataitem2', 'dataitem3' etc.

This is how for I have gotten with my XAML code:

```
<ListView IsEnabled="{Binding TestSelectorEnabled}" x:Name="ListView1" DataContext="{Binding TestsViewModel.TestsDataTable}" ItemsSource="{Binding TestsViewModel.TestsDataTable}" SelectedValue="{Binding TestsViewModel.SelectedTest}" SelectedValuePath="TestName" Height="180" View="{Binding TestsViewModel.GridView}"  TabIndex="0" MinWidth="1" Focusable="False">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="{Binding TestsViewModel.ListItemCounter, StringFormat='dataitem{}{0}'}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

But this gets me this Error for every ListViewItem:

**System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'TestsViewModel' property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView' (HashCode=33913349)'. BindingExpression:Path=TestsViewModel.ListItemCounter; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=33913349); target element is 'ListViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'AutomationId' (type 'String')**

So I tried and played around with the RelativeSource like this:

```
<ListView IsEnabled="{Binding TestSelectorEnabled}" x:Name="ListView1" ItemsSource="{Binding TestsViewModel.TestsDataTable}" SelectedValue="{Binding TestsViewModel.SelectedTest}" SelectedValuePath="TestName" Height="180" View="{Binding TestsViewModel.GridView}"  TabIndex="0" MinWidth="1" Focusable="False">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="{Binding TestsViewModel.ListItemCounter, StringFormat='dataitem{}{0}', RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Which gets me this error:

**System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=TestsViewModel.ListItemCounter; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'AutomationId' (type 'String')**

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to give your window the correct data context.

It could look like this:

```
 xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ViewModels"            
 d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:TestsViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"

<ListView IsEnabled="{Binding TestSelectorEnabled}" x:Name="ListView1" DataContext="{Binding TestsViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding TestsDataTable}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTest}" SelectedValuePath="TestName" Height="180" View="{Binding GridView}"  TabIndex="0" MinWidth="1" Focusable="False">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="{Binding ListItemCounter, StringFormat='dataitem{}{0}'}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: indeed it was the datacontext that was not set up right. I will post my solution below it's too long for a comment

Answer (score 0):

Below my working XAML code:

```
<ListView IsEnabled="{Binding TestSelectorEnabled}" x:Name="ListView1"  ItemsSource="{Binding TestsDataTable}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTest}" SelectedValuePath="TestName" Height="180" View="{Binding GridView}"  TabIndex="0" MinWidth="1" Focusable="False">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.TestsViewModel.ListItemCounter, StringFormat='dataitem{0:F0}', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```